# Solve $y'' + y = \sec^2 x, 0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The equation: $y'' + y = \sec^2 x, 0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$

I can't seem to find $u'/v'$ values. My system of equations is:

$u' \sin x + v'\cos x = 0$

$u' \cos x - v'\sin x  = \sec^2 x$

I believe that $u = ∫\sec xdx$ and $v = ∫\sec x \tan xdx$, but I cannot for the life of me get these equations to solve for those integrations. Any ideas?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I think $v$ should be $-\int\sec(x)\tan(x)dx$. This should make the equations work.

Comment: This is a pretty complicated system, and would be best to solve via cramer's rule. I don't see any cheap ways to get the solutions.

Comment: What are your questions exactly? How to solve the system of equations, or how to solve the integrals $u$, $v$?

Comment: What is the complementary function? What is the particular integral? See if you can find them. And post your progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard problem for variation of parameters.

$y''+y = 0$ has the solution $y=c_1 cos(x) + c_2 sin(x)$

Let:

$$Y = u(x)cos(x)+v(x)sin(x)$$

$$Y' = u'cos(x)+v'sin(x)-usin(x)+vcos(x)$$

We have an extra degree of freedom, so with that, let:

$$u'cos(x)+v'sin(x) = 0$$

$$Y' = -usin(x)+vcos(x)$$

$$Y'' = -u'sin(x)+v'cos(x)-ucos(x)-vsin(x)$$

plugging this into the differential equation, and using our earlier condition, we get the system:

$$-u'sin(x)+v'cos(x) = sec^2(x)$$

$$u'cos(x)+v'sin(x) = 0$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
        cos(x) & sin(x)\\
        -sin(x) & cos(x)\\
        \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
        u'\\
        v'\\
        \end{bmatrix}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
        0\\
        sec^2(x)\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
        u'\\
        v'\\
        \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
        cos(x) & -sin(x)\\
        sin(x) & cos(x)\\
        \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
        0\\
        sec^2(x)\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
$$u' = -sin(x)sec^2(x) = -tan(x)sec(x)$$
$$v' = sec(x)$$

solving for $u$ is trivial, as it is a well-known integral formula.

$$u = -sec(x)+C_u$$

To solve for $v$, multiply $sec(x)$ by $\frac{sec(x)+tan(x)}{sec(x)+tan(x)}$, and then make the substitution $s = sec(x) + tan(x)$, so that $ds = sec^2(x)dx + sec(x)tan(x)dx$. The integral then becomes trivial to evaluate, with the solution:

$$v = ln(tan(x)+sec(x))+C_v$$

Therefore, the solution to the differential equation is:

$$y = C_1 cos(x) + C_2 sin(x) - (sec(x)+C_3)cos(x) + (ln(tan(x)+sec(x))+C_4)sin(x)$$

Comment: $C_3$ and $C_4$ can be combined into the homogeneous part.